# htpasswd — не подходят старые пароли

Tags: ubuntu, apache, apache2

Был сервер на Ubuntu с Apache и PHP. На сайте была аутентификация (Apache Basic Authentication). Пароли генерировались в PHP таким образом:

```
$password=crypt($password);
```

Какой метод хеширования был настроен, и каким образом, мне было неинтересно. Генерирует пароли, да и ладно.

Перенес сайт на новый сервер с Ubuntu 15.04, PHP 5.6.4, Apache 2.4.10.
И перестал пускать по паролям вида:

```
user1:$6$CB/mFomB$7RPHkrzaOAzxqkUYQXccePVACerVsZfED.hoDofBnHNSfx5NOUnhtcKB6ImOrE.d/xDNMU6B7tqipWm1Qzw3k.
user2:$6$rbBZzWeo$lmBqIwiLcYEblULhc.oUhYCEC.YEokOJ1lpnyyUgCjWs6B4e6JXOOe0fVPAa9TasdpvWJgd8xeoi.VYHtfc3j/
```

Определил, что это хэш SHA-512.

Пробовал генерировать хэш с помощью htpasswd, хэш короткий, но все работает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как заставить Apache проверять пароли в SHA-512?

Comment: Не очень-то похоже на sha512, скорее что-то типа bcrypt

Comment: на старой системе какие первые 3 символа были у хешей?

Comment: Пишут что: "[CRYPT_SHA_512] - SHA-512 hash with a 16 character salt starting with $6$."  Эти хэши со старой системы.

Comment: Попробуйте `$password = crypt ($password,'$6$');` вероятно на разных системах поддерживаются разные алгоритмы хеширования.
... или я совсем не правильно понимаю суть проблемы

Comment: Да, эта функция делает правильный хэш. crypt ($password,'$6$CB/mFomB') это для первого хэша из приведенный как пример. Но беда в том, что видимо apache (или что-то другое?) не распознает пароль связанный с этим хэшем.

Comment: а в чём, собственно, проблема? сами пароли утеряны? так сгенерируйте новые.

Comment: не уверен, но в доке https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/password_encryptions.html я не вижу SHA-512, самый длинный хэш у bcrypt

Comment: много пользователей с паролями.
Странно как-то. Покапаюсь еще. Наверное придется перегенерировать..

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

если вам известны эти пароли:

```
user1:$6$CB/mFomB$7RPHkrzaOAzxqkUYQXccePVACerVsZfED.hoDofBnHNSfx5NOUnhtcKB6ImOrE.d/xDNMU6B7tqipWm1Qzw3k.
user2:$6$rbBZzWeo$lmBqIwiLcYEblULhc.oUhYCEC.YEokOJ1lpnyyUgCjWs6B4e6JXOOe0fVPAa9TasdpvWJgd8xeoi.VYHtfc3j/
```

проверьте на той системе, где у вас стоит «новый» *apache*, точно ли эти хэши соответствуют тому, что генерируется:

```
$ mkpasswd -m sha-512 пароль соль
```

*соль* — это, в данном случае, то, что между вторым и третьим знаком `$`.

для `user1` соль — это `CB/mFomB`, для `user2` — `rbBZzWeo`